# "Yet while the lowering of the wealth prerequisite provided an easy target for modern liberals..."

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the following [passage](http://www.sparknotes.com/history/european/1871-1914/section1.rhtml), in which sense was the phrase **easy target** used ?

1.Lowering of the wealth prerequisite was an easy job to succeed.

2.Lowering of the wealth prerequisite issue could be used for manipulating the political scene and igniting protest .Because it was obvious injustice in the country.

> The extension of the voting franchise that began in England in 1832
>   with the Great Reform Bill initiated, albeit slowly, a process of
>   liberalization unseen in the history of the British Parliament.
>   Previously, power rested in the hands of the few aristocrats with
>   enough property and wealth to pass a relatively high property
>   requirement for voting and holding office.
>
> **Yet while the lowering of the wealth prerequisite provided an easy
>   target for modern liberals when arguing for the democratization of
>   Parliament, this democratization at first did not extend to the
>   working class.**
>
> Most representatives in the Commons came through Eton to either
>   Cambridge or Oxford where, under the tutelage of the same professors,
>   these future leaders developed a similar outlook on the world: the
>   superiority of the British system, the rightness of imperialism, the
>   power of industry, the benefits of trade, and the value of general
>   isolation from the Continent. These views, though subject to some
>   slight degree differences between Liberals and Conservatives, remained
>   common through most of the House. Such views did not square with the
>   new concerns of the workers who had neither received an elite
>   education, nor, in some cases, an education at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether it means that the task was easy, or merely was the starting point for a broader campaign: both.

It means that of the possible approaches to the democratization of parliament, this was (somehow) an easy one for these "modern liberals" to achieve. The passage implies that the goal of these folk was democratization (somewhat anachronistically, in my opinion, but that's by-the-by) and this was a good place to start because it was easier than other changes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be 2. The biggest indicator here is the use of the word *obvious*. When something is obvious it requires little effort to notice- it's *easy* or in this case, an *easy target*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I used the word obvious, it is not in the original passage which can be seen on the question

Comment: Oh, haha. I guess I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: it is ok. I just gave two possible meanings that I inferred from the passage and asked which one correct is.

Comment: Now that I read into it further, it seems that how you say "manipulating the political scene" is a bit unnecessary and perhaps should be left out. Also there are some other structural flaws so a good correction might look like: "The wealth prerequisite was an obvious injustice and this could be enough to ignite protest." Does that help?

Comment: :) I asked about the meaning of " easy target" ..these are my comments